# ASP.NET MVC 3 Routing Multiple parameters without query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the below route setup but it is not coming out the way I am expecting. Yes I am still new to MVC.

The way it is coming out is like this.

```
http://localhost:29998/Home/States?make=Chrysler
```

the way I want it to come out is like this

```
http://localhost:29998/Home/Chrysler/States
```

Then of course once you click on your state it would look like this.

```
http://localhost:29998/Home/Chrysler/Florida
```

I would realy love to be able to remove "home from that altogether and just leave it as

```
http://localhost:29998/Chrysler/States

routes.MapRoute(
                "States", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{make}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "States", Make = "" } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Comment: Ok so if I put a URL like this
http://localhost:29998/Home/States?make=Chrysler 
and I put a break point on the return I see that string make has the value of Chrysler
 
but if I use this URL the string make takes a null value. 
http://localhost:29998/Home/States/Chrysler
Im sure there is something small I am over looking that I should be doing I just cant seem to think of what it is

Comment: 'public ActionResult States(string make)
 {
 IEnumerable<DealerHolder> stateNames = new List<DealerHolder>();
 stateNames = _repository.GetAllDealers();
 var states = from state in stateNames
 where state.make == make
 orderby state.address.city ascending
 select state.ToDomainDealer();
 return View(states.ToList<DealerHolder>());
 }'
 

'routes.MapRoute(
 "States", // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}/{make}", // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "Home", action = "States", make = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
 );'

Comment: How are you generating the link?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink(item.make, "States", new { make = item.make })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
localhost:29998/Chrysler/States

routes.MapRoute(
                "States", // Route name
                "{make}/{states}/", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "GetStateData", make="", states="" } 
            );
```

You should place it below the default routing method so it does not take your controller values.

Comment: it should work place a debug point and check the parameter values.  It must be like make = home, state = index.  So to avoid this add more routes like "home"/{action}/{id} for ever controller