# Routing without query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have added the following route before the default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "RecordDefault",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "Record" }
);
```

I can hit the page I want using: sitename/Person/Record/John

But I have an global search in the navigation with the following code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Record", "Person", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left" }))
{
       @Html.TextBox("name", "", new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Search Name" })
}
```

When I submit the form the following URL is displayed: sitename/Person/Record?name=John

What do I have to do to ensure the URL is formatted without the query string parameter?

Thanks

Not the same as the posted duplicate, that marked answer does not resolve my problem and according to the comments it also didnt work for others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 3 Routing Multiple parameters without query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791778/asp-net-mvc-3-routing-multiple-parameters-without-query-string)

Comment: Marked answer in this still leave the query string in the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form generates `../Person/Record?name=John` because a browser has no knowledge of your routes (which is c# code running on your server). And the HTML standards require that the value of successful form controls be added as query string values when the method is GET.

In order to generate your preferred url (`../Person/Record/John`), you need javascript to intercept and cancel the default submit, and build a url to navigate to. Using jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var baseUrl = $(this).attr('action');
    // or var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("Record", "Person")';
    var url = baseUrl + '/' + $('#name').val();
    location.href = url; // redirect
    return false; // cancel the default submit
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this does format the URL the correct way but when I dedug the controller the name value is null even though its correct in the URL. Really odd behaviour.

Comment: Actually sorry this works perfectly. I had been fiddling around with the routes and had the default one placed before the name parameter one! Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

Use form post `FormMethod.Post` instead of Get. So the value will be not appeared in querystring.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Record", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left" }))
{
       @Html.TextBox("name", "", new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Search Name" })
}
```

Comment: I had this first but it doesnt include the searched name anymore. I want it to read sitename/Person/Record/John. I thought having the addition routing in place would have formatted it the way I want like it does with id parameters

Comment: @BadDub use attribute routing which includes the John for ex: sitename/Person/Record/{name} or try this in routeconfig defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "Record", name = UrlParameter.Optional } //name parameter same as mehod param

Comment: This still seems to produce the URL with the ?name= query string

Answer (score -1):

In your Controller add the following -

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Record(string name)
    {
        //code for what needs to be performed.
        return View();
    }
```

In your view add the following code replacing your existing and check -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Record", "Person", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.TextBox("name")
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: That is effectively what OP already has (and will not generate the value of  the textbox as a route paremeter - just a query string parameter)!